# model, model_name, None if model_only else prep_pipe, verbose, **kwargs NameError: name 'prep_pipe' is not defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlflow

I have a model in pickle format ,when i am trying to save that model to my local i am getting this error,model is trained on pycaret,
can someone tell me what is wrong

```
from asyncore import read
import logging
import pickle
import mlflow
from numpy import save
from setuptools import setup
import wrapper
import os
import sqlite3
import sqlalchemy
import sys
from mlflow.models.signature import infer_signature
from pycaret.classification import save_model
class MlflowModelService:

   def saveModel(self,model,variant,readable_model_id,preprocess_file_path=None):
    print('inside storeModel of model service.......')
    readable_model_id = readable_model_id.replace("/","__$__")
    model_name = "Original-Model"
    with mlflow.start_run() as active_run:#mlflow work starts
        active_run = mlflow.active_run()

        #mlflow.keras.save_model(model,model_name) #Save a scikit-learn model to a path on the local file system
        #print(model , model_name)
        #exp_clf101 = setup(data = dataset, target = 'result', use_gpu=False, silent=True)
        save_model(model , model_name)#ERROR ON THIS LINE
        pyfunc_model_uri = self.logModel(readable_model_id,model_name,preprocess_file_path)
        self.registerModel(pyfunc_model_uri,readable_model_id)
```